# How to post index of 2 dimensional object array element via url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

Can not post index of 2 dimensional object array element via url post in javascript. The idea is by clicking REMOVE option for each array element to delete current element and display the refreshed array on document body.

My code is here:

```html
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
  var arr = {
    Monday: [
      ["web programming", "class", "11:50"],
      ["web programming II", "class", "13:40"],
      ["programming", "class", "17:50"]
    ],
    Tuesday: [
      ["web programming I", "class", "10:50"],
      ["programming II", "class", "15:40"],
      ["programming", "class", "17:50"]
    ],
    Wednesday: [
      ["web tech I", "class", "11:50"],
      ["web programming II", "class", "18:40"],
      ["functional programming", "class", "17:50"]
    ],
    Thursday: [
      ["DBMS", "class", "11:50"],
      ["web tech", "class", "13:40"],
      ["linear programming", "class", "17:50"]
    ]
  };

  disp();

  function removeElm(index_no) {
    //function removeElm(row_no, index_no){
    //console.log(row_no, index_no);
    var newarr = arr.Monday.splice(index_no, 1); // Instead of Monday need to put 'ROW' itself
    console.log(arr);
    disp();
  }

  function disp() {
    var str = "";
    for (row in arr) {
      str += "<h3>" + row + "</h3><div>";
      for (elem in arr[row]) {
        str += arr[row][elem] + "</sup><a href=# onClick='return removeElm(" + arr[row].indexOf(arr[row][elem]) + ")'>REMOVE</a>";
        //str += arr[row][elem] + "</sup><a href=# onClick='return removeElm(" + arr[row].indexOf(arr[row][elem]) + "," + row + ")'>REMOVE</a>";
      }
      str += "</div>";
    }
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = str;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: what's not working?

Comment: It's mostly working but OP doesn't want to hardcode in `Monday` inside the `removeElem` function. OP's looking for a way to pass this information from the `onClick` handler so any day of the week can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`removeElm` needs two arguments, the object key and the array index.

```js
var arr = {
  Monday: [
    ["web programming", "class", "11:50"],
    ["web programming II", "class", "13:40"],
    ["programming", "class", "17:50"]
  ],
  Tuesday: [
    ["web programming I", "class", "10:50"],
    ["programming II", "class", "15:40"],
    ["programming", "class", "17:50"]
  ],
  Wednesday: [
    ["web tech I", "class", "11:50"],
    ["web programming II", "class", "18:40"],
    ["functional programming", "class", "17:50"]
  ],
  Thursday: [
    ["DBMS", "class", "11:50"],
    ["web tech", "class", "13:40"],
    ["linear programming", "class", "17:50"]
  ]
};

disp();

function removeElm(row_no, index_no) {
  arr[row_no].splice(index_no, 1);
  console.log(arr);
  disp();
}

function disp() {
  var str = "";
  for (row in arr) {
    str += "<h3>" + row + "</h3><div>";
    for (elem in arr[row]) {
      str += arr[row][elem] + "</sup><a href=# onClick='return removeElm(\"" + row + "\", " + arr[row].indexOf(arr[row][elem]) + ")'>REMOVE</a>";
      //str += arr[row][elem] + "</sup><a href=# onClick='return removeElm(" + arr[row].indexOf(arr[row][elem]) + "," + row + ")'>REMOVE</a>";
    }
    str += "</div>";
  }
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: That's it, what I exactly looking for. So solution is, passing row argument like a string. Thank you so much, for your help.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer:

You need to pass `row` as a string to your `onclick` function. To do this you need to escape the quotations within your altered markup:

```
   str += arr[row][elem] + 
                "</sup><a href=# onClick='return removeElm(\"" + 
                row + 
                "\"," + arr[row].indexOf(arr[row][elem]) + 
                ")'>REMOVE</a>";
```

And then alter the function to receive an additional parameter:

```
    function removeElm(row, index_no){
        var newarr = arr[row].splice(index_no,1); // Instead of Monday need to put 'ROW' itself
        disp();
    }
```

### Example:

```js
var arr = {
                        Monday: [
                                    ["web programming", "class", "11:50"],
                                    ["web programming II", "class", "13:40"],
                                    ["programming", "class", "17:50"]
                                ],
                        Tuesday: [
                                    ["web programming I", "class", "10:50"],
                                    ["programming II", "class", "15:40"],
                                    ["programming", "class", "17:50"]
                                ],
                        Wednesday: [
                                    ["web tech I", "class", "11:50"],
                                    ["web programming II", "class", "18:40"],
                                    ["functional programming", "class", "17:50"]
                                ],
                        Thursday: [
                                    ["DBMS", "class", "11:50"],
                                    ["web tech", "class", "13:40"],
                                    ["linear programming", "class", "17:50"]
                                ]
            };

        disp();

        function removeElm(row, index_no){
            var newarr = arr[row].splice(index_no,1); // Instead of Monday need to put 'ROW' itself
            disp();
        }

        function disp(){
            var str = "";
            for(row in arr){
                str += "<h3>" + row + "</h3><div>";
                for(elem in arr[row]){
                    str += arr[row][elem] + 
                    "</sup><a href=# onClick='return removeElm(\"" + 
                    row + 
                    "\"," + arr[row].indexOf(arr[row][elem]) + 
                    ")'>REMOVE</a>";
                }
                str += "</div>";
            }
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = str;
        }
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

---

### Aside - Additional Changes:

It's worth noting that using `onclick` in general doesn't allow for clean code, but **especially** when you're programatically generating the function call.

Basically, this code is difficult to maintain and not exactly easy to read.

A better solution would do the following:

- Utilize JavaScript to add Events and Listeners
- Create Explicit Areas in Your Code

For instance, in the below example, after the design you only have to worry about the initialization which simply looks like this:

```
let parent = document.querySelector("#result");
display(data, parent);
```

---

### Example:

```js
var data = {
   Monday: [["web programming", "class", "11:50"], ["web programming II", "class", "13:40"], ["programming", "class", "17:50"]],
   Tuesday: [["web programming I", "class", "10:50"], ["programming II", "class", "15:40"], ["programming", "class", "17:50"]],
   Wednesday: [["web tech I", "class", "11:50"], ["web programming II", "class", "18:40"], ["functional programming", "class", "17:50"]],
   Thursday: [["DBMS", "class", "11:50"], ["web tech", "class", "13:40"], ["linear programming", "class", "17:50"]]
};

function display(data, parent) {
   // HELPER FUNCTIONS / SETUP
   let create = (tag, options = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), options),
       _container = () => create("div", { className: "classContainer" }),
       _heading = textContent => create("h3", { textContent }),
       _class = info => create("span", { textContent: info.join(" ") + "\t" }),
       
       _removeButton = (day, item) => {
          // create button
          let removeBtn = create("button", { textContent: "Remove" });
          
          // add event listener
          removeBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            
            let btn = event.currentTarget;
            data[day].splice(item, 1);

            btn.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(btn.parentNode);
      });
      return removeBtn;
   };

   // WORK
   
   Object.entries(data).forEach(function ([day, _classes]) {
      // add heading
      parent.append(_heading(day));
      
      // add each class and remove button
      _classes.forEach((classInfo, classIndex) => {
         let container = _container();
         container.append(_class(classInfo), _removeButton(day, classIndex));
         parent.append(container);
      });
      
   });
}

// INIT

let parent = document.querySelector("#result");
display(data, parent);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Dear zfrisch, thank you for your help and suggestion.